# Insert value that was inserted into another table

Tags: mysql

I have created a `tickets` table that holds ID's for everything so they can all be unique. The `tickets` table is inserted with new data BEFORE insert on other tables. I need to put the ID that was generated in the `tickets` table into other tables in one fell swoop.

Here's how it will run;

1. Query to insert data into `table1`
2. Trigger insert of the `ref` and an auto incremented ID in `tickets`
3. `ID` from tickets inserted back into `table1` as well as the data from the first query.
4. More goes on after this but that's sorted.

Here's what I have so far.

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER status_ref BEFORE INSERT ON status
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 INSERT INTO tickets SET ref = S;

 END;
|

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you rethink your numbering scheme: Right now, you are double-linking: The `tickets` table refers to the details via `ref`, and the details table refers to the `tickets` table via its `ID`.

This is not a good idea: Think of a later update to one of the tables, that desynchronizes this double link: Either you disallow that, which renders the second number absolutely meaningless, or you allow it, in which case you end up with different results depending on which field you use for a `JOIN`.

You should chose a numbering scheme with one leading table - I personally would simply drop the requirement to link `tickets.ID` back into the details table.

**Edit**

Seems this was a misunderstanding of my part as for the meaning of the `ref` field - judging by the other comment, I was not alone with this.

If the `ref` field carries information about the **type** of reference only, you have an easy option: create an additional field `refID` on the `tickets` table, that stores the (auto incrementing) ID field of the details table. You would need something like

```
ALTER TABLE tickets ADD COLUMN refID INT NOT NULL;

-- the following only if you not already have it
ALTER TABLE status ADD COLUMN ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;

CREATE TRIGGER status_ref BEFORE INSERT ON status
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 INSERT INTO tickets SET ref = S, refID=NEW.ID;
END;
```

This stores the detail-table ID in the `tickets` table.

Comment: listen to this.  The original question is an example of a really  absurd database design.

Comment: I understand this, slightly. How can I link an individual row in `tickets` to it's details in another table?

Comment: @EugenRieck The way I thought of it at the moment was that the ref just refers to what table the ID is for. I am guessing that is a stupid way to do it. How should I do it?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect this